# How to search up for an schemas array index inside a Mongoose model

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following document, where `globalData` is an array inside of my `globalEventSchema`.

```
{
  "globalData": [
    {
      "event": "event-a",
      "generatedId": "969046612024361060",
      "_id": "626a0d5553e6eb2f5e1ce714"
    },
       // More instances of the Schema
  ],
  "__v": 0
}
```

I want to search through my `GlobalEvents` and find the `globalData` array where the `event` matches my given string. How can I achieve that using mongoose?

Comment: It's better if we know the name of the schema.

Comment: Hi @DylanL., the name of the Schema is globalEventSchema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will look in the `globalData` array for the specified `event`

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const { event } = req.body;
  const globalEvent = await GlobalEvent.findOne({
    'globalData.event': event,
  });
  if (globalEvent) {
    res.json(globalEvent);
  } else {
    res.json({
      error: 'No global event found',
    });
  }
});
```